# SmartGWT slow images rendering

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a SmartGWT 2.0 application where I have to render a few hundred small images and this is taking very, very long (>20s). It's a intranet application.
Do you have any idea how I could speed up the rendering?
Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned it's an intranet application but the network or server could still be a culprit.  You can use Firebug's "Net" panel to see the network delays from fetching the images.  If those are the problem, there's no fix within your SmartGWT Java code.

If rendering speed is the problem, what approach are you using?  For this volume of images you probably want to use simple HTML  tags inside of a SmartGWT Canvas via Canvas.setContents().

Comment: I'm generating dynamically Img objects. Network delays are insignificant, I had a look with Firebug. I'll try to use Canvas.setContents(). 
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but if it can help others people.

I would take a look at this :

> An image bundle is a construct used to improve application performance
>   by reducing the number of round trip HTTP requests to the server to
>   fetch images. GWT can package many image files into a single large
>   file to be downloaded from the server and managed as a Java object.

It's very useful 
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiImageBundles