# Problem with Listgrid in smart gwt

Tags: image, rendering, smartgwt

I am using a List Grid in my application. Each cell of the list grid can contain images and hyper links. the number of images and hyperlinks will be determined at run time. I have made the first column to be frozen. The List grid takes a lot of time to get loaded and also it takes a lot of time when I scroll horizontally. I tried using a canvas and setting image and anchor html tags as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154881/smartgwt-slow-images-rendering/). Still I am facing the same issue. [image: The left most column [Time] is frozen and the no. columns to its right is arbitary. also, the cell can contain upto 16 vertical bars differentiated by colours]

Updated: Initially, I got a warning asking me to setRecordComponentHeight since i have overridden the record component. Now, I have set that but still I have issues with the row height. The warning is not displayed now.

[image]

Any help will be really useful.

Comment: can you add the code that generates this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the issule in ListGrid of Smartgwt that When Records are more and U are using createrecordcomponent for generating icons for delete or edit or any other button...At that time Not all the buttons were displayed...It is depending on the height.As height is more...More Buttons will be displayed...So it was my problem...

Solution:

You need to just add the listgrid.draw() property if it is not added previously...If it is there...then no need to add that...That's all...